# Iterate over object properties and omit certain ones

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out the best way to iterate over an object's properties so I can build a sql query for an insert or update.  I also am looking to be able to omit certain fields in the iteration.

Below is an example object where I would like to grab name and age but omit employer because that is a join from another table.

```
class person
{
     private $_name, $_age, $_employer;

     public function get_name()
     {
          return $this->_name;
     }
     public function get_age()
     {
          return $this->_age;
     }
     public function get_employer()
     {
          return $this->_employer;
     }
}
```

I could cast an object as an array to get the properties but I still don't have a good way to omit certain properties.

```
$personObj = new person();
foreach((array)$personObj as $k => $v)
{
     $sql .= "...";
}
```

Comment: Do you want to get the values from inside of the class or outside? Also have you tried something to get to your goal?

Comment: I'm trying to get the values outside the class.  I'm not sure the best way to approach this to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this gives you a hint

```
class person
{
     private $_name = 'dude';
     private $_age = '27';
     private $_employer = 'yes';

     public function get_name()
     {
          return $this->_name;


     }
     public function get_age()
     {
          return $this->_age;
     }

     public function get_employer()
     {
          return $this->_employer;
     }
}

$person = new person();
$required = array('name','age');
foreach($required as $req)
{
    $func = "get_{$req}";
    echo $person->$func();
}
```

https://3v4l.org/vLdAN

Comment: Thanks for that example.  That definitely helps give me direction.

Comment: Dude, saved my time, +1